# Proving Metrizability is a topological property

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am self studying Topology from C.Wayne patty and I am unable to prove this question.

Adding it's image -> [image]

Note that $\rho$(x, y) = $d(f^{-1}(y_{1}) , f^{-1}(y_{2})  )$ ( it's cut in the image) .

> I am unable to prove 2 questions-> (1) It has to be shown that it is a metric .

Here I am unable to prove that it follows Triangle inequality. I tried by putting a $f^{-1} (z) $ in $\rho( y_{1} , z) $ ( so I had to prove $d(f^{-1}(y_{1}) , f^{-1}(y_{2})  )\leq d(f^{-1}(y_{1}) , f^{-1} (z)  )+ d(f^{-1}(z), f^{-1}(y_{2})  )$  but cannot form a relation so as to prove the required thing. It seems that homeomorphism has to be used .

> (2) Also can you please tell how to prove that topology induced by $\rho $ is $ Tau $ ( Cursive T) .

I shall be really thanful.

Comment: You already know that $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality (it is a metric on $X$), so you are done. You also know that $d$ induces the topology on $X$ and $f$ is a homeomorphism, so can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space (with corresponding topology $\mathcal{T}_d$) and $(Y,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space, such that we have a homeomorphism $f:X \to Y$, then (for convenience) let $g: Y \to X$ be the inverse function, which exits as $f$ is a bijection. Then define $d_f: Y \times Y \to \Bbb R$ by $d_f(y,y') = d(g(y), g(y')$ and the triangle inequality is simple to see: let $y,y',y'' \in Y$ and note that $d_f(y,y'') = d(g(y), g(y'')) \le d(g(y), g(y')) + d(g(y'), g(y'')$ (by the usual triangle inequality for $d$ applied to $g(y), g(y'), g(y'') \in X$) and the latter equals $d_f(y,y')+d_f(y',y'')$ by definition and we're done. So every property of $d_f$ just comes back to that same property for $d$ but applied to their $g$-images. The fact that we have an injection $g$ is essential in $$d_f(y,y')=0 \iff d(g(y), g(y')) = 0 \iff g(y)=g(y') \iff y = y'$$ etc. So indeed $d_f$ is a metric on $Y$. What do its balls look like?

$$y' \in B_{d_f}(y,r) \iff d_f(y, y') < r \iff d(g(y), g(y')) < r \iff g(y') \in B_d(g(y), r) \iff \\ y' \in f[B_d(g(y), r)] \text { as } f = g^{-1}$$

It follows that $$B_{d_f}(y,r) = f[B_d(g(y), r)]$$ and as $f$ is open and $B_d(g(y), r) \in \mathcal{T}_d$, we know that $B_{d_f}(y,r) \in \mathcal{T}$. And as every $O$ open in $X$ is union of open $d$-balls, every open subset of $Y$ is a union of open $d_f$-balls too, so $Y$ is metrisable.

Comment: Brandsms how did you wrote the argument after it follows that...  ie how did you wrote $ B_{d_{f}}(y, r) = f[B_{d} ( g( y) , r) ] $ ? Please elaborate!! Before that it's completely clear.

Comment: @User the string of equivalencies before shows the equality of those sets. A point is in one iff it is in the other.

Comment: How did you deduced that topology induced by $\rho$  is $ Tau $ . ( Capital T) ? Kindly explain that!!

Comment: Can you please answer my above question?

Comment: @User that’s by definition as $X$ is metrisable.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection and $d$ is a metric on $X$, then this formula defines a metric on $Y$. To prove the triangle inequality between some three points in $Y$, just pull all three points back to $X$.

To show that this metric yields the same topology, just observe that $f^{-1}$ defines an isometry, and hence a homeomorphism $(Y,\rho)\to(X,d)$. Since $f\colon (X,d)\to (Y,\mathscr T)$ is a homeomorphism, it follows that the identity on $Y$, equal to $ff^{-1}\colon (Y,\rho)\to (Y,\mathscr T)$ is a homeomorphism, so the topologies are the same.

Comment: how does $ f f^{-1}$ being homeomorphism implies topologies are same? Which results you are using? Please prove it!!

Comment: @User: Just the definition of a homeomorphism.

Comment: This proof is slick, but you can also show that open balls in $Y$ are open in $Y$ and that open sets in $Y$ are covered by open balls to make it possibly a bit more transparent.

Comment: @JustinYoung: Yes, you can do that. Whether that is more transparent or not --- I guess it is a matter of taste.